# Share common functions across multiple CI folders

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter

I am having multiple CI folders each for a new site in my htdocs folder, here i want to share some common functions across all of these folders.
i have configured my virtaul host as follows.

```
<VirtualHost *>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/portal1" 
    ServerName test.exp1.org
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/portal1">
        Order allow,deny Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/portal2"
    ServerName test.exp2.org
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/portal2">
        Order allow,deny Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Each portal folder contains its own CI,but there are many functions which are replicated in each folder so i want them to be stored somewhere common so both folders can use them.

What is the proper methodology to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could split each application on its own folder as guided [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/managing_apps.html)

And then on each index.php file for each application share the same "system" folder so you use the same CI version, so let's say you have:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\
```

As your apache root (which is the webserver xampp uses) then you would want to put the system folder outside public visible folder:

```
C:\xampp\system
```

And then you would have each application like this:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\portal1
C:\xampp\htdocs\portal2
C:\xampp\htdocs\portaln...
```

Once you did that, make sure that each index.php inside those *portalN* folders point to the same system folder:

```
$system_path = '../../system';
```

I would highly recommend renaming "system" to something more meaningful like "codeigniter-2.1.4" or whatever version you are using since it tells you at least which version each of your web applications is using.

Finally, you can just create a new [helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/helpers.html). Which is available app-wise without instantiating anything from CI. You'll just have to either load it manually:

```
$this->load->helper('helper_name');
```

Or autoload it in autoload.php if you plan to use it in more than one controller/model/view:

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('helper_name');
```

And the trick here is to put your helper inside your "system/helpers" folder instead of putting it on each application folder, that way, since CI is actually loaded from the system folder, it will load also your helper for all apps too.